# multiple versions of tables in mysql8

Tags: mysql

I have a database in MySQL8. I am running MySQL8 server as a docker container. I have a table 'A' in the database to which I added some data earlier. Recently, I deleted all data in table 'A' and added new data. Over the past few days, I noticed that when I query data from 'A', I get previous data and not the latest data. But after a few times the select query is run, I get the new data. I am not sure what is happening here. Is it possible that MySQL is maintaining some kind of cache or versions of the table internally? How do I make sure that the old data is 'actually' deleted from the server?

Comment: looks like you connecting to different DBs.

Comment: no, I am connecting to the same database host. everything is the same- host, database, table - except the data.

Comment: No. you are not connecting to same. This is docker. Isn't docker is just a container and if the underlying OS restores hard drive, you get previous version? In any case, how is this a programming question? This is environmental. May be DBA forum can answer this

Comment: sure, thanks for pointing it out. I have posted this question in the dba stack exchange forum.